# Is it possible to create a static map from a Mapbox frontend map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a Mapbox map that I give the user on the frontend. It has markers automatically placed. I then allow the user to manipulate the map, changing the zoom, pitch, markers, and draw polygons. After the user made changes, I want to be able to export it as a static map.

Looking at the Mapbox api, it looks like I need to supply geojson and marker data to it, as well as the lat/long, bearing, pitch, etc.

However, I am not sure how to serialize a Mapbox, or if I even can. And if I can't do that, then I'd have to individually extract each data field from the Mapbox UI element before calling the Mapbox api to generate a static map. I can can extract *most* of the data through the viewport when it's changed, but it is unclear if pin data can be extracted. I haven't been able to find anything about this use case in their documentation.

Ultimately my question boils down to 'is it possible to create a static map directly from the Mapbox object, using either the JavaScript SDK or the Mapbox API?

Thanks

I am using Uber's [React-Map-GL](https://github.com/uber/react-map-gl) if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code for specifically anyone else using the Uber React-Map-GL package on how to export it to a PNG clientside.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    viewport: {
      width: 800,
      height: 600,
      latitude: 37.7577,
      longitude: -122.4376,
      zoom: 8,
      preserveDrawingBuffer: true, // Needed to allow export as png
    },
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.mapInstance = this.mapRef.getMap()
}

buttonPress = () => {
  console.log('png = ')
  console.log(this.mapInstance.getCanvas().toDataURL())
}

<button onClick={() => this.buttonPress()}>Click</button>
<ReactMapGL
  ref={map => (this.mapRef = map)}
  {...this.state.viewport}
  mapboxApiAccessToken=tokenhere
  onViewportChange={viewport => this.setState({ viewport })}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a client side snapshot example at https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/pull/6846/files though it won't capture Marker's, you'll need to use Symbols instead.

Comment: Interesting... if I want to use markers do you think the next easiest way would be to export the canvas and then convert the canvas to a PNG?

Comment: The example I linked to does exactly that, it exports the canvas to PNG. GL JS Markers are HTML DOM elements, not in the canvas. So you'll need to use Symbols or write your own code to render those Markers on a canvas.